# program that accepts an integer value & computes the remaining days

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView output;
    EditText month, day;
    Button compute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        day = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        compute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        compute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int x = 0, y = 0, result = 0;

                x = Integer.parseInt(month.getText().toString());
                y = Integer.parseInt(day.getText().toString());

                if (x == 1 && y <= 31) {
                    result = 359 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 2 && y <= 28) {
                    result = 328 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 3 && y <= 31) {
                    result = 297 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 4 && y <= 30) {
                    result = 267 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 5 && y <= 31) {
                    result = 236 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 6 && y <= 30) {
                    result = 206 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 7 && y <= 31) {
                    result = 175 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 8 && y <= 31) {
                    result = 144 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 9 && y <= 30) {
                    result = 114 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 10 && y <= 31) {
                    result = 83 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 11 && y <= 30) {
                    result = 53 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                } else if (x == 12 && y <= 31) {
                    result = 22 - y;
                    output.setText(result + "Days Before Christmass");
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

here is my revised code from my previous question about an android program that accepts an integer value & computes the remaining days  now i'm getting an error on my output instead of getting 2-359 = 357 i get an answer of 327 days before Christmas.. your help is much appreciated

Comment: FYI `2-359 = -357` and not 357

Comment: What are your inputs? I assume x is 1, what is y?

Comment: @thegrinner y is the day and x is month..that makes if (x == 1 && y <= 31) x the months in numerical form and y is the days

Comment: sorry about that typo @PedroOliveira

Comment: Sorry, I mean the actual values you're using that give you the incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

So you're getting the answer for 1/2 not 2/1. Check that month and day are being entered into the correct slots (System.out.print() is your friend here).

Also, you've misspelt Christmas.

Comment: will do.. sorry about that

Comment: thanks bro the error was in this part of the code  day = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); it was diff. from my xml file

Answer (score 0):

So seeing your problem your telling that for the month 1 and for the days 2 you get the wrong result.

So by your code if x==1 and y==2 the output would be 357 indeed. However, if you missplaced your edittext the result would be 327 which is x==2 and y==1. That's what you get. So I you should change

```
 day = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

to

```
 day = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```